# Is kirby worth it

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I am more of a ness main but I am really good at using kirby but I keep seeing kirby go to the very bottom of every tier list, I wanna know if using kirby is still worth it

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Sorry but questions asking for opinions are off-topic here.

Comment: no I was finding if there is a technical advantage with using kirby, because I am good at it and I want to make the learning really worth doing

Comment: I believe it's hard to answer this with facts...

Comment: Why don't you do what you think is good for you, not what you think is advantageous? If you're using Ness as your main fighter, why not just use him & improve it? It's not like you can handle two characters at the same time.

Comment: Why can't you handle two characters at the same time?  I think you can easily main two characters.

Comment: @Millard What I meant to say was "you wouldn't be able to use them at the same time". It doesn't mean "you can't have two main fighters at the same time". Yes, I (technically) main two fighters, but I don't commit to the "second main" as much as I do to the "first main". Second main is only used every two or three weeks. I guess my wording was bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are good at Kirby, use him.  I know some people who kill with him.  Tier lists really don't matter, if a player works for you, it works for you, any character can compete.  If you get to a point with Kirby that you can't really improve any further and aren't at the skill level you want, you can always go back to Ness, but he's fun to play and you seem to want to try him, otherwise you wouldn't have made a post.

So if you want my opinion, go for it.

As for techical advantage:

His down special is deadly and highly spammable.  His suck ability is incredibly annoying to deal with.  He's fast.  He has some dash attacks that work well for crowd controll.  His hammer ability can do good damage if you can contact with it.  His high number of jumps combined with his up special makes recoveries easy.  At the end of the day, it's not the character that makes the win, but the player.

P.S.  When I said any character can compete, I meant any character except Olimar and Wii Fitness Trainer.

Comment: Just as a note, an Olimar player has a number of high-profile tournament wins, and Wii Fit can definitely hold their own with a crazy projectile game. As you said, any character is viable. :)

Comment: fair enough =)  .

Comment: I held the #1 spot in my city with Wii Fit when I was still playing competitively (pre-pandemic). Don’t you be talkin’ crap on my girl :p

Comment: wow I was very new to smash when i wrote that lol.  Olimar and Wii fitness trainer are both excellent characters and very viable for high level play.  =D